# How to continuously update (terminal-like) a wxPython TextCtrl

Tags: python, python-2.7, wxpython

I'm working on a wxPython GUI for [esptool.py](https://github.com/espressif/esptool/) i.e. the app will invoke that script. For starters I'd like to redirect the content that esptool.py prints to console to a TextCtrl. I followed a [frequently referenced article](http://www.blog.pythonlibrary.org/2009/01/01/wxpython-redirecting-stdout-stderr/) for that and it works well.

However, I'm currently stuck dealing with the [progress monitor that esptool.py prints to console](https://github.com/espressif/esptool/blob/master/esptool.py#L592). It prints something like "25%" followed by a number of `\b` which immediately erase what was printed, then "26%" which again is erased immediately and so on.

The plan was to parse the string, `TextCtrl.AppendText()` everything but the backspace characters and then `TextCtrl.Remove()` as many characters as there are backspace characters.

The below code works fine when I step through it with the debugger but it crashes hard when "let loose". There seems to be some timing/threading issue. Apparently I can't call `TextCtrl.Remove()` right after `TextCtrl.AppendText()`?

```
class RedirectText:
    def __init__(self, textCtrl):
        self.out = textCtrl

    def write(self, string):
        new_string = ""
        number_of_backspaces = 0
        # this could definitely be improved performance wise...
        for c in string:
            if c == "\b":
                number_of_backspaces += 1
            else:
                new_string += c

        self.out.AppendText(new_string)
        if number_of_backspaces > 0:
            last_position = self.out.GetLastPosition()
            self.out.Remove(last_position - number_of_backspaces, last_position)

    def flush(self):
        None
```

The code that calls esptool.py runs in its own thread as to not hog the main UI thread.

This is my first real Python project (and thus the first w/ wxPython of course) and I haven't coded for the desktop in many years. So, it's entirely possible I'm missing something obvious.

Comment: Just found out about `wx.CallAfter` that I need to wrap the `TextCtrl` operations with in my case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the sake of completeness here's (one of) the solution(s).

Turns out that manipulating the text control with `wx.CallAfter` in quick succession isn't too reliable wrt `GetLastPosition()`. So, it now just appends the text and remembers how many characters to remove the *next* time `write()` is invoked. It then removes those characters before appending the new text.

```
class RedirectText:
    def __init__(self, text_ctrl):
        self.out = text_ctrl
        self.pending_backspaces = 0

    def write(self, string):
        new_string = ""
        number_of_backspaces = 0
        for c in string:
            if c == "\b":
                number_of_backspaces += 1
            else:
                new_string += c

        if self.pending_backspaces > 0:
            # current value minus pending backspaces plus new string
            new_value = self.out.GetValue()[:-1 * self.pending_backspaces] + new_string
            wx.CallAfter(self.out.SetValue, new_value)
        else:
            wx.CallAfter(self.out.AppendText, new_string)

        self.pending_backspaces = number_of_backspaces

    def flush(self):
        None
```